# Route [foo/1/bar] not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Route [foo/1/bar] not defined. Found in resources/views/bar/create.blade.php

This is in routes/web.php;

```
Route::post('/foo/{client}/bar', 'BarController@store');
```

This is the line which is causing the issue;

```
form action="{{ route('foo/'.$client->id.'/bar') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what should do is

```
form action="{{ url('foo/'.$client->id.'/bar') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

since you did not define name route like this

```
Route::post('/foo/{client}/bar', 'BarController@store')->name('bar_post');
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

I changed

```
Route::post('/foo/{client}/bar', 'BarController@store');
```

To

```
Route::post('/foo/{client}/bar', 'BarController@store')->name('bar_post');
```

And this

```
form action="{{ route('foo/'.$client->id.'/bar') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

To this

```
form action="{{ route('bar_post', ['client', $client->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```